# Generate Semantic HTML forms

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

I want to use zend framework forms generation and validation techniques, but I don't want the generated html script to be generated as HTML Table script .

I want it to be generated as div not table, or I want to echo each element generated inside the HTML that I had built.
Can I make something like this??

Comment: Have no idea :) But know this, the form system is going to change dramatically in beta4 so don't code using beta3 methods

Answer (score 0):

ZF project lead Matthew Weier O'Phinney showed [this sample code](http://git.mwop.net/?a=viewblob&p=PhlyContact&h=0472ddec711a623008fbd82b7877018111e4e13c&hb=16da5bc0f302d068b5c916d55bbe1c8e1b1674de&f=view/phly-contact/contact/index.phtml) today for generating forms with the new Zend_Form, scheduled for release in the upcoming Zend Framework 2 beta 4.

It seems that the old decorator-based approach is being replaced with a more straightforward way to mark up your forms in your view script however you like.

For example, if you pass a form instance to your view model, the view script could do something like this:

```
<?php
$form = $this->form;
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>
<div class="my_form">
    <div class="element">
        <div class="label"><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('from')); ?></div>
        <div class="input"><?php echo $this->formInput($form->get('from')); ?></div>
        <div class="error"><?php echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('from')); ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
echo $this->form()->closeTag($form);
```

Comment: Yes, I had found this way of writing forms, but I didn't know how to make filters and validations for these elements !

Comment: I'm not sure if things have changed for zf2, but in zf1, all the form validation was done server side, so it didn't have anything to do with rendering. If you want client side validation, then you need to use something like Dojo ValidationTextbox.